# How to update hstore columns in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Is there a way to restrict what `hstore` columns can be saved? I've got below code for doing this so far:

```
store_accessor :widget_locations, :left_area1, :mid_area1, :left_area2, :mid_area2, :right_area2
```

but this seems to still allow other key names to be saved ie. middle_area123

Also how am I able to update `hstore` like `update_attributes` or `update`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could be wrong but my guess is that you are making calls on `widget_locations` like

```
item.widget_locations[:left_area1] = thing
```

If so, you should change that to

```
item.left_area1 = thing
```

because you told the `store_accessor` to create attributes `:left_area1, :mid_area1, :left_area2, :mid_area2, :right_area2` that will be serialized to database column `:widget_locations`. Now these attributes will behave like *normal* attributes, so you can put validations on them etc.

This also allows you to update an item as usual:

```
item.update(name: 'Test', left_area: 'garden', mid_area: 'livingroom')
```

The catch with a `hstore` is that accessing the serialized column *will* allow you to add new unknown attributes, so it is best to directly access the attributes you explicitly specified.